# Report file Print (Multiple objects) c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, report, rdlc

I've been working on a project in C# which uses a RDLC report with an Excel file as its source.

My problem is that I have made a single rectangle on the report, and I want it to be printed multiple times on the page (i.e. On an A4 size paper, when I print it, I want 10 prints of the rectangle on the page [5 on left and 5 on right side of the page]).

I am getting 5 prints of the rectangle on the left side only. What should I do to get 10 prints (as described above)?

How can I use the Page Break functionality in the RDLC to accomplish this?